# Powershell: equivalent of Perl's 'for' command?

Tags: powershell, for-loop, replace

I've used this sort of thing countless times in Perl:

```
for ( $someVariable ) {
    s/findthis/replaceitwiththis/g;
    s/findthat/replaceitwithsomethingelse/g;
}
```

The value of `$someVariable` is temporarily in `$_` and the variable is updated "in place"; each new substitution command continues to update/overwrite the variable's contents. It's a handy and compact way to get a lot of changes done in a simple loop.

Does Powershell have an equivalent of this use of "for"?

***Adding comment following response from @neolisk, so that I can use formatting.***

```
$s = 'abcde'
$s | foreach {
    $_ -replace 'a','x'
    $_ -replace 'e','z'
}
write-host "And: $s"
```

Result seen on-screen:

```
xbcde
abcdz
And: abcde
```

Also tried `$_ = $_ -replace 'a','x'` and so forth. There must be some additional syntax required here to get the "in-place" substitution...

***Further edit following reply from @Nacht***. This works, though I'm not crazy about the back-ticks:

```
$s = 'now is the time for all good individuals blah blah'
Write-Host $s
$s = $s `
  -replace "now", 'NEVER' `
  -replace 'time', 'moment' `
  -replace "blah\s+blah", '-- oh, WHATEVER'
Write-Host $s
```

Output:

```
now is the time for all good individuals blah blah
NEVER is the moment for all good individuals -- oh, WHATEVER
```

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly like this in Powershell, but the syntax is slightly different:

```
$someVariable | foreach {
    Write-Host $_;
}
```

If you want to do in-place replace, keep in mind that `$_` is immutable, i.e. readonly. The proper way would be to output new string on pipeline and collect into another variable, so for your example it can look like this:

```
$s = 'abcde' 
$newS = $s | foreach {
    $_ -replace 'a','x' -replace 'e','z'    
}
write-host "And: $newS";
```

Comment: (Added comment in the main body of the question as comment box doesn't seem to support full text formatting. Hope that isn't a case of _'don't do that on StackOverflow'_.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
$s = 'abcde'
$s = $s -replace 'a','x' -replace 'e','z'
write-host "And: $s"
```

output:

```
And: xbcdz
```

you could also do it on several lines like this:

```
$s = 'abcde'
$s = $s -replace 'a','x'
$s = $s -replace 'e','z'
write-host "And: $s"
```

---

the following doesn't work because each line is outputed separately:

```
$s | foreach {
    $_ -replace 'a','x'
    $_ -replace 'e','z'
}
```

the following doesn't work because assignment statements don't output anything:

```
$s | foreach {
    $_ = $_ -replace 'a','x'
}
```

Comment: The goal is to have the variable's value updated "in place".  

Hoped-for result: `And: xbcdz`

Comment: edit should give you the solution you want - i simply added `$s = ` to the beginning of the foreach

Comment: Or perhaps there's no need for `foreach`. Perhaps this is good enough: `$s = $s -replace 'a','x' -replace 'e','z'`. A vague imitation of a loop can be created by adding line breaks and using back-ticks in the appropriate places. The back-ticks make it look a bit klutzy but the line breaks make it a bit easier to read. Still I don't know if it's considered **the** right way to do it in Powershell.

Comment: ha oh right of course - you can simply do `$s = $s -replace 'a','x' -replace 'e','z'`

Comment: you may want to do each `-replace` on a separate line. most string operations do not require using foreach to get each individual chraacter in powershell - usually they can be dealt with using the functions/methods/operators available

Comment: what do you mean about line breaks and backticks?

Comment: I have just added more text to the main body of the question, again to be able to use more formatting than is available in the comment boxes. The addition hopefully explains what I mean.

Comment: There's nothing ridiculous about escaping line-breaks when you want to continue a command on the next line (unless your programming language requires a terminating character like `;` for each statement, that is). If you don't want wrapped lines, you can split the replacements into separate instructions: `$s = $s -replace 'a','x'; $s = $s -replace 'e','z'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's appropriate here to answer my own question in this way. If not, please advise. To sum up several approaches (all checked):

```
$s = 'abcde' (likewise for all below)
$s | foreach {
    $_ `
    -replace 'a', 'X' `
    -replace 'e', 'Z'
}
```

Displays `XbcdZ` during execution. $s *unchanged*.

```
$s = $s `
    -replace 'a', 'X' `
    -replace 'e', 'Z'
```

$s is updated "in place"; value is now `XbcdZ`

```
$t = $s | foreach {
    $_ `
    -replace 'a', 'X' `
    -replace 'e', 'Z'
}
```

$s *unchanged.* Value of $t: `XbcdZ`

```
$t = $s `
  -replace 'a', 'X' `
  -replace 'e', 'Z'
```

$s unchanged. Value of $t: `XbcdZ`

```
($t = $s) `
  -replace 'a', 'X' `
  -replace 'e', 'Z'
Write-Host "`$s: $s -- `$t: $t"
```

Added the parens to see what might happen.

Neither variable's value changes. `XbcdZ` is printed to the console *above* the line printed via Write-Host.